# Is there anything that allows a java code to return to line 1?

Tags: java

Is there an option to make the entire script/ program go back to line 1, 2 or 3?
Is it possible or should i look into another option because this one is doomed to fail?
(Yes i'm an idiot at this and completely new)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a do-while loop instead and enclose your statements in it, to keep on looping whatever statements you want to re-execute instead of complicating it by returning to the start of execution